# How to capitalize first occurrence of each character in a string

Tags: java

If I have a String, e.g. "aabccdeef"

How can I capitalize only first occurrence of each char so that the result is "AaBCcDEeF"?

Comment: Question is not clear, it says "first occurrence of each character", but the example has the same characters grouped next to each other.  What is the output of a String of `abcabc` vs `aabbcc`.  If the `String` is guaranteed to be grouped by character, the answer has different possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way (since I love java streams)

```
 public static String capitalizeFirstOccurrence(String str) {
    var alreadyOccurred = new HashSet<String>();
    return str.chars()
            .mapToObj(x -> String.valueOf((char) x)) // convert to single char String
            .map(character -> {
                if (alreadyOccurred.contains(character)) {
                    return character;
                }
                alreadyOccurred.add(character);
                return character.toUpperCase();
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    var input = "aabccdeef";
    var output = capitalizeFirstOccurrence(input);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this but is there a more simple method to acheive this

Comment: Maybe by using a library, but i can't think of a more simple way. Streams are really powerful and efficient and `String.chars()` returns a Stream right away without splitting, which would involve pattern matching (using regex, even if split on `""` empty string (e.g. `str.split("")`)) which I think is less performant than using the native `String.chars()` for big Strings. Unfortunately it returns an `IntStream` so you must cast to char. Since it's ugly and confusing (imho) to work with ASCII codes directly (substract 32 to code for uppercase) you must cast it to use `String.toUpperCase()`

Comment: A Set/List to track already occured chars is always necessery to "remember" that a character already occured. 
And of course you could do all this inside a loop, but I find streams way more ellegant :)